# Alternative to Thread.Sleep() before socket read

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, ftp, network-programming

I'm using this FtpClient library to connect to mainframe from WinForms application. I'm using thread.Sleep for the thread to wait for the response before it starts reading, otherwise it freezes. Is there an alternative to do this?

```
public void Login() 
{
    if (this.loggedin) this.Close();

    Debug.WriteLine("Opening connection to " + this.server, "FtpClient");

    IPAddress addr = null;
    IPEndPoint ep = null;

    try
    {
        this.clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        addr = Dns.Resolve(this.server).AddressList[0];
        ep = new IPEndPoint(addr, this.port);
        this.clientSocket.Connect(ep);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // doubtfull
        if (this.clientSocket != null && this.clientSocket.Connected) this.clientSocket.Close();

        throw new FtpException("Couldn't connect to remote server", ex);
    }

    **Thread.Sleep(4000);**
    this.readResponse();
    ...
}

private void readResponse()
{
    this.message = "";
    this.result = this.readLine();

    if (this.result.Length > 3)
        this.resultCode = int.Parse(this.result.Substring(0, 3));
    else
        this.result = null;
}

private string readLine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        this.bytes = clientSocket.Receive(this.buffer, this.buffer.Length, 0);
        this.message += ASCII.GetString(this.buffer, 0, this.bytes);

        if (this.bytes < this.buffer.Length) break;
    }

    string[] msg = this.message.Split('\n');
    if (this.message.Length > 2)
    {
        this.message = msg[msg.Length - 2];
        try { response = msg[msg.Length - 3]; }
        catch { }
    }
    else
    {
        this.message = msg[0];
    }

    if (this.message.Length > 4 && !this.message.Substring(3, 1).Equals(" ")) return this.readLine();

    if (this.verboseDebugging)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.Write(msg[i], "FtpClient");
        }
    }
    return message;
}

public void sendCommand(String command)
{
    if (this.verboseDebugging) Debug.WriteLine(command, "FtpClient");

    Byte[] cmdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((command + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
    clientSocket.Send(cmdBytes, cmdBytes.Length, 0);
    this.readResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use async programming model:

```
socket.BeginConnect(ep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), socket);

void Connected (IAsyncResult result)
{
    var socket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;

    // do the stuff

    socket.EndConnect(result);
}
```

Comment: Its working for logging in, but while sending other commands(upload/download) i'm getting this error "Cannot block a call on this socket while an earlier asynchronous call is in progress.".

Comment: @user558138: Sorry forgot to say that you need to call `EndConnect()`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.
clientSocket.Send(cmdBytes, cmdBytes.Length, 0); //on this line

Comment: @user558138: Where do you put your `Send`?. Check out also [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if you can work with .NET 4.0, you've the task API.

You may learn more by reading this article: http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/01/25/NET-40-and-SystemThreadingTasks.aspx

It provides you a way of creating a flow in which a task waits until previous one has ended. Take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Writing `Thread.Sleep()` is indeed a bad practice.

If you are actually doing a FTP client, use [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8exfzxft.aspx) [BeginGetResponse(asynccallback, object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

And pass the `readResonse` as a callback. It will be called exactly when the response is ready.

Comment: Bad practice? I think not. But yes, there are other approaches that can work.

Comment: Ok, let's say it's a proof of bad design, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457282/alternatives-to-thread-sleep-for-simulating-pauses

Comment: i dont agree with that article. its speculative about why you use a thread.sleep(). sleeping a thread is in my book a good way of saying "i dont have anything to do, please do process something before i try again". Still. My idea of a decent sleep is on <100 milliseconds, not on seconds or minutes.

Comment: Looping when you actually need to wait for a result is a waste of CPU time. I think an asynchronous call is a better design.